# Prefer mobile over WiFi connection

Tags: android, wifi

My application performs WiFi operations and therefore it needs to stay on the same connection under the whole session.

I have looked at the ConnectivityManager class, but haven't figured out if it's a good idea to use it.

Is there any way to make the application prefer mobile over WiFi connection?

Will ConnectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature force all applications to use the mobile connection? How about ConnectivityManager.setNetworkPreference?

Should I call ConnectivityManager.stopUsingNetworkFeature when I'm finished?

How does requestRouteToHost work? Does it add an entry to the routing table? If so, this tries to make all data to the specified host will go through that interface?

Thanks

Comment: "My application performs WiFi operations and therefore it needs to stay on the same connection under the whole session." -- That is not possible. You cannot force the user to not move.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to make the application prefer mobile over WiFi
>   connection?

You can set preference.

```
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

connectivityManager.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);  // Preferring mobile over wifi 



Dont forget to change it to default in onStop or onDestroy

connectivityManager.setNetworkPreference(ConnectivityManager.DEFAULT_NETWORK_PREFERENCE);
```

Comment: Will it force the whole system or only the app to use the mobile connection?